# Best GUI Miner - To use with slush pool

Tags: mining-pools, cgminer, gpu-mining, mining-software, cpu-mining

I have recently wanted to get into mining some crypto currency. And would like to use a GUI based miner for ease and convenience.

But I haven’t found any that seem to be any good yet it that are easy to manage and control.

Any suggestions would be fantastic